# With Python, Can a discord bot interact with a messages component as an event or command? Message.component.actionrow.button?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord-buttons

So i've been working on creating a bot that has a few specific functions that it will do. I'm able to engage in commands and events, but i'm wanting to set something up in an event.

So i have an event set up that is an on_message to do an action. The problem is what i'm wanting to do with the message concerns an interaction. So when the message comes up, and i look at the code to it, it has a components section and then there are Actionrows within the components. The first row [0] in particular when i drill into it. There are 5 buttons in the row and i want to engage the second button interaction.
I can't directly think of a way to do this, and i'm hoping someone may have an idea how to trigger this interaction, then i could build that into my event to interact with it anytime this particular message comes up.

Appreciation for any help.